# Java, How to get nodes of elements in element with specific argument in XML file

Tags: java, xml, dom

I need to parse XML file, output. I know how to handle the simplest ones, but I don't know what to do in case an unknown amount of elements in other elements using DOM parser. Example:

```
<server>
    <users id="1">
        <no id="106">
            <name>Pat</name>
            <email>p@exemple.com</email>
        </no>
        <no id="554">
            <name>Bon</name>
            <email>b@example.com</email>
        </no>
    </users>
    <users id="2">
        <no id="612">
            ...
            ...
```

I know how to print all 'no' elements, but I must separate them. Mainly, I must specify in output to which 'user' element these 'no' elements belong.
Maybe there is a method which counts elements contained in another element with a specified argument ('id' in 'users'). Thank You.

Actually, I want to output:

```
Root Element: server

Pack of users: 1

Current Element: no
User no: 106
Name: Pat
E-mail: p@exemple.com

Current Element: no
User no: 554
Name: Bon
E-mail: b@exemple.com

Pack of users: 2
User no: 612
Name: ...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign the unknown number of elements to a `List<Node>` variable and iterate over it:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.Node;
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;

class Users {
    public static void main (String... args) {
        try {
            Document dom = new SAXReader().read(new File(args[0]));
            System.out.println("Root element: server\n");
            List<Node> packs = dom.selectNodes("/server/users");
            for (Node pack : packs) {
                System.out.println("Pack of users: " + pack.valueOf("@id") + "\n");
                List<Node> users = pack.selectNodes("no");
                for (Node user : users) {
                    System.out.println("Current element: no");
                    System.out.println("User no: " + user.valueOf("@id"));
                    System.out.println("Name: " + user.valueOf("name"));
                    System.out.println("E-mail: " + user.valueOf("email") + "\n");
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```